# Uncaught exception

Tags: c++

Why is the exception thrown from `getA()` not caught?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{

protected:
    int a;
public:
    Base() { a=34; }
    Base(int i){ a = i; }
    virtual ~Base() { if(a<0) throw a; }
    virtual int getA()
    {
        if(a < 0) { throw a;}
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Base b(-25);
        cout << endl << b.getA();
    }
    catch (int) {
        cout << endl << "Illegal initialization";
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

I understand what you are saying about stack unwinding.
If I change `Base` to the below, I now get my "Illegal initialization" debug to print.  Why am I not getting a call to `terminate()` any longer?

```
Base() { a=34; }
Base(int i){ a = i;  if(a<0) throw a;}
virtual ~Base() { if(a<0) throw a; }
virtual int getA()
{
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you call `getA()` the first exception is thrown, so-called [stack unwinding](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr155.htm) starts and the object gets destroyed. While the object is being destroyed its destructor throws another exception that escapes the destructor's body and (since that happens during stack unwinding) this leads to `terminate()` being called immediately by the C++ runtime and [your program terminates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507697/57428).

In the second snippet you submitted the exception is thrown in the constructor, so the constructor doesn't complete and the destructor is never called (since destructors are only called for fully-constructed objects), hence no chance for `terminate()` call.

Comment: @Nim: Not to "never throw", but rather to "never let it propagate outside the destructor".

Comment: Last question. How should the first snippet be modified in order to catch destructors exception?

Comment: @Nim: Be careful of the phrase never throw in a destructor. As the destructor may hide the throwing of exceptions by calling methods/functions that potentially throw. So the trick is exceptions in a destructor are fine, as long as they do not escape.

Comment: @Display Name: Just don't let exceptions escape the destructor.

Comment: @Martin and sharptooth, pity you can't edit comments that have been marked up, I would have changed it a while ago.. I guess my point was that the original code was actually *throwing* in the destructor, but I should have said "never throw and never propagate"... c'est la vie...

Comment: @Display Name, the line `if(a<0) throw a;` in the destructor serves no purpose.. you don't need it...

Answer (score 2):

`terminate()` is no longer called because you're throwing the exception in the constructor now. So the object is not actually created. Hence the destructor is never called.